# Devops Query Search - Find all tickets starting with

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

Does anyone know how in the devops queries under boards I would search for all pbi titles that start with a word? The query editor only seems to have contains and contains word. This doesn't really work as we only want to search for any cards starting with a specific word and not anything containing that word.

It's probably not possible but I was wondering if anyone knew any tricks to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such query operator. Neither Work Item Queries nor Semantic Search support a "Starts with" operator. If you're using a standard prefix, maybe Tags or an Area Path are better ways to classify your item. A custom field may also be an option.

If you want to do more advanced queries, a script relying on the REST API may be able to do the "Contains" query to reduce the number of hits, then relying on local filtering to do the "Starts with". A couple of lines of PowerShell will probably do it.

```
az boards query --wiql "select * from workitems where System.Title contains 'make'" --organization https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing | 
    ConvertFrom-Json | 
    ?{$_.fields."System.Title" -like "Make*" }
```